# CorePlot: How to display x from 0 to 40?

Tags: ios, iphone, core-plot

I know how to display an x-Axis with values from -1 to 40:

```
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-1.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(40.0)];
```

But the user still can scroll the graph to values above 40. How do I prevent this?

Comment: That statement will make a range enclosing values from -1 to 39 ((-1) + 40).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `allowsUserInteraction` to `NO` on the plot space to turn off user scrolling.

If you still want to allow scaling but limit the maximum visible area, set the `globalXRange`.

Comment: This will disable scrolling, yes, but any other user interaction like pinch scaling etc., too? Isn't there a better, more granular way?